# base_controller package

Tags: ros, ros-arduino-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi
Does anyone know a package for base controller for differential mobile robot which subscribes twist messages and publishes odom to ardunio board??
I know ros_arduino_bridge and a package named ardros but because i dont have their hardtware like motor and encoder shields i need to change them in deep. thanks:))

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193602/base_controller-package/) by [mohammad](https://answers.ros.org/users/19955/mohammad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2014-09-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

have you looked at the [rosserial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial) package? Specifically at the [rosserial_arduino](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials), it has a lot of tutorials on how to use ROS code on Arduino. It is not a complete base_controller but you can program it to get what you need.

Regards,
Gary

---

Originally posted by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) with karma: 962 on 2014-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mohammad](https://answers.ros.org/users/19955/mohammad/) on 2014-09-27**:
yes i have looked. But as you said it does not have a tutorial or something like it to for example send a velocity command to DC motors by arduino. Is there any good source that i could learn these programmings between arduino and ROS except these tutorials???

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2014-09-28**:
I have a pretty generic application of rosserial for a diff robot that takes in cmd_vel and publishes odom from encoders. If you want take a look [ros_arduino](https://github.com/tonybaltovski/ros_arduino), it can easily be changed to used different motor drivers.